# How to define a function to be a callback implementation in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I defined a `@callback` that way :

```
/**
 * @callback MyClass~Handler
 * @param {string} target
 * @param {Options} options - Original options
 */
```

I use it to define my class prototype :

```
/**
 * @param {string} name - The name
 * @param {MyClass~Handler} handler
 * @private
 */
MyClass.prototype._builder = function(name, handler) { //...
```

But how to tell JSDoc that the following function has the same definition as my `MyClass~Handler` (something that would be like `@isacallback` in the following code)?

```
/**
 * Default handler
 * @isacallback {MyClass-Handler}
 * @private
 */
MyClass.prototype._defaultHandler = function(target, options) { // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but since `@callback` just defines a type, couldn't you use the `@type` declaration?

In other words:

```
/**
 * Default handler
 * @type {MyClass-Handler}
 * @private
 */
MyClass.prototype._defaultHandler = function(target, options) { // ...
```

See http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html for further info on `@type`.

Comment: Not really, because the `@type` defines a class (a type as you said), so I can't describe the function parameters for example with that annotation...

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding: `@type` isn't used to define a class (that's what `@typedef` is for).  The `@callback` defines the type (because `@callback` is basically just `@typedef` limited to functions), and then you reference that definition using `@type` (the way you wish you could with the non-existent `@isacallback` tag).

Comment: While this would make sense, jsdoc displays it as a member rather than method though it does at least link to the correct type in the right manner. If you add `@function` (to try to clarify this is a method), then the docs mistakenly show `@type` as its *returns* type.